# Why is message put into a dead-letter queue (MSMQ)?

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq, dead-letter

Preamble:
I have a web application, which sends MSMQ messages (with UseDeadLetterQueue = true) from time to time. I can also see that some of those messages are put into a system dead letter queue. However, I can't see the failure reason directly from "Computer Management" console. 

I found the following resource:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789035(v=vs.110).aspx, 

which allows to check message status and failure. But it's usable only in WCF scope (as it uses OperationContext).

---

Basically checking message status and failure reason is what I need, but how can I configure a WCF service to listen to a dead-letter queue and track all the messages put inside, regardless of sender?

Or is there any other (non-WCF) way to get reason of why specific message was put into a dead letter queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked article you found tells you how to create a WCF service that takes messages off the DLQ. Note that it tells you you must use AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any to pull all messages off regardless of sender.

Note: by the time the message ends up on the DLQ, you will not have information about the reason this occurred. Regardless of whether or not you're using WCF that information isn't stored in the queue.

If for example your recipient is a WCF listener using the MSMQ binding any exception thrown will cause the message to fail to get delivered. MSMQ will retry for a while and then eventually give up and put the message in the DLQ. So if you wanted to know the original reason you need to add some tracing in your WCF service to catch and trace thrown exceptions.